# Mkdocs: On blog-style site, how do I make Next button go to chronologically next topic?

Tags: mkdocs, mkdocs-material

I've set up an mkdocs site using the Material theme where my topics are in reverse chronological order - that is, the most recent is at the top of the nav set.

Unfortunately this means my Next and Prev buttons take you to the prev-in-time and next-in-time topics.

What's the quickest way to resolve is?

I tried making some changes to footer.html but while I could get the buttons to change I couldn't get the formatting right.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you figure out how to change, then whenever you run `mkdocs build`, the changes will be lost.
The best way I can think of is reverse your current order in your `mkdocs.yml`'s nav section.

In case, if you still want to modify html file, then let say's my **previous button** goes to **about.html** page and I want it to go to **more.html** page, then I should do the following in my html file

Replace `<a href="about.html"` with `<a href="more.html"`

You need to do something similar.
Thanks :)